# Global variable not defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my case why arr is not defined? I saw the error in jsfiddle's console log. Supposed it's a gobal variable so it can be access in any function scope? 
http://jsfiddle.net/xgpqe4rv/3/

```
$(function() {

    autoSlide = setInterval(cycle(), 3000);


    arr = [{
            'logo': 'http://placehold.it/50&text=1'
        },

        {
            'logo': 'http://placehold.it/50&text=2'
        },

        {
            'logo': 'http://placehold.it/50&text=3'
        },

        {
            'logo': 'http://placehold.it/50&text=4'
        }

    ];

    $('img').attr('src', arr[0]['logo']);

    function cycle() {

        var i = 1;

        $('img').attr('src', arr[i]['logo']);

        if (i == 3) {

            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;

        }
    };

    $('#right').click(function() {
        cycle();
    });
});
```

Comment: @R3tep why? give me a reason

Comment: `autoSlide = setInterval(cycle(), 3000);`  <--- wrong

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not declaring your variables with `var`
2. `autoSlide = setInterval(cycle(), 3000);` you are passing the return value of the function to the interval, whereas you want a function `reference`.

`autoSlide = setInterval(cycle, 3000);`

or

```
autoSlide = setInterval(function() { cycle() }, 3000);
```

Comment: Maybe more clear to say that he is passing the return value of the function invocation, which is probably nothing.

Comment: oh I see, what a careless mistake I did. But now I'm confused more with variable declaration. I thought without var the variable can be a global var?

Comment: @JamesLemon Yes, it is a global variable, which is exactly why it's wrong. Global variables are bad news. Moreover, global state is bad news.